# Haproxy check if only key exists

Tags: haproxy

I am using haproxy as a load balancer. I have a specific condition for some criteria.

I need to make sure that the query params of logout should starts with http or https. If the query param value is not starting with http or https I simply need to deny the request.

I have checked so many condition but it doesn't seems to work for me.

I've tried the following

```
acl url_param1 urlp_reg(logout) ^(http|https)://.*$
http-request deny if url_param1
```

The above command will block all the URL's even if the URL doesn't have the logout key in URL.

I need to allow if the URL doesn't have logout param in URL. I just want to blok only if the logout parameter value doesn't starts with http/https.

Suggest me the condition for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of how this behaves does not make sense -- as written, it should deny if the parameter exists and does begin with http(s).

The correct logic is this:

```
http-request deny if { url_param(logout) -m found  } !{ urlp_reg(logout) ^(http|https)://.*$ }
```

Deny the request if the parameter exists and the parameter does not begin with http(s)://.